# create react app(typescript) adding env file to production build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I am using

```
react-scripts-ts 2.16.0.
```

Env files works brilliant as described in official [docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables)

Anyway maybe I misunderstood how it should work, anyway when I am running

```
yarn start
```

every call in code correspond to env file value so:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_CODE
```

will return value from .env file from root of project for example:

```
REACT_APP_SECRET_CODE=abcdef
```

So everything works like a charm, but for me most important is production build. When I am running

```
yarn build
```

I don't see any .env file in build folder, and even when I will put .env file(with value REACT_APP_SECRET_CODE=smth_new) into every folder from build folder, values are never overwritten and I always get abcdef printed.

Why production build not contain .env file and why I cannot add my own .env file to production build?

Answer (score 0):

you've probably found the answer up until now but I thought why not help a little.

`.env` files are/should be in your `.gitignore` file. This means that they will not be pushed to your remote repositories and nor will they be built to production. It would be unsafe to do so because otherwise anyone with access to your files would see your passwords and client secrets etc.

What you should do for this, is configure the environment variables on your build server specifically.